# _io.BytesIO file handle not recognized as bytes

Tags: python

I've recently started using the `BytesIO` class from `io`.  It's very handy and has solved my initial problem, but now I've created another for myself.  In short, we'll be working with Azure Functions or DataBricks (which one TBD) and won't have local file storage but will have blob storage.  I'm using `io` to get around that.  So, there's a model file in blob storage that I get:

```
blob_name = 'my_model_file.model'
blob_client = BlobClient( account_url    = account_url,
                          container_name = container_name,
                          blob_name      = blob_name,
                          credential     = credential)
download = blob_client.download_blob().content_as_bytes()
saved_model_fh = BytesIO(download).getvalue()
print(type(saved_model_fh))
```

The output is `<class 'bytes'>`.  So, as far as I know, that gives me what I need.  But when I try to use this for gensim Doc2Vec.load:

```
model = Doc2Vec.load(saved_model_fh)
```

I get this error at the end of the traceback:

```
TypeError: endswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str
```

Perhaps I'm naive, but it seems plain that I am giving it bytes, as it wants, not a str.  When I run `type` on the exact object I feed it, it says that it's bytes.  What am I missing here?  I'm happy to post more of the traceback, but I suspect I'm missing something basic here.

Edit:  Traceback added:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[76], line 18
     13 print(type(saved_model_fh))
---
---> 18 cpc_model                 = Doc2Vec.load(saved_model_fh)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\gensim\models\doc2vec.py:809, in Doc2Vec.load(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    786 """Load a previously saved :class:`~gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec` model.
    787 
    788 Parameters
   (...)
    806 
    807 """
    808 try:
--> 809     return super(Doc2Vec, cls).load(*args, rethrow=True, **kwargs)
    810 except AttributeError as ae:
    811     logger.error(
    812         "Model load error. Was model saved using code from an older Gensim version? "
    813         "Try loading older model using gensim-3.8.3, then re-saving, to restore "
    814         "compatibility with current code.")

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py:1942, in Word2Vec.load(cls, rethrow, *args, **kwargs)
   1923 """Load a previously saved :class:`~gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec` model.
   1924 
   1925 See Also
   (...)
   1939 
   1940 """
   1941 try:
-> 1942     model = super(Word2Vec, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
   1943     if not isinstance(model, Word2Vec):
   1944         rethrow = True

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py:484, in SaveLoad.load(cls, fname, mmap)
    455 """Load an object previously saved using :meth:`~gensim.utils.SaveLoad.save` from a file.
    456 
    457 Parameters
   (...)
    480 
    481 """
    482 logger.info("loading %s object from %s", cls.__name__, fname)
--> 484 compress, subname = SaveLoad._adapt_by_suffix(fname)
    486 obj = unpickle(fname)
    487 obj._load_specials(fname, mmap, compress, subname)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py:573, in SaveLoad._adapt_by_suffix(fname)
    558 @staticmethod
    559 def _adapt_by_suffix(fname):
    560     """Get compress setting and filename for numpy file compression.
    561 
    562     Parameters
   (...)
    571 
    572     """
--> 573     compress, suffix = (True, 'npz') if fname.endswith('.gz') or fname.endswith('.bz2') else (False, 'npy')
    574     return compress, lambda *args: '.'.join(args + (suffix,))

TypeError: endswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str
```

Comment: Please post the complete traceback

Comment: "_happy to post more of the traceback_" Why are you teasing us? Duh, yes, [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) more of the traceback. I'm missing something basic here... **the traceback**.

Comment: What is `BytesIO(download).getvalue()` supposed to do? You're initializing a buffer with some bytes, and then immediately extracting those bytes back out. If you need `bytes`, just use `download`. If you need a file-like object, use `BytesIO(download)` without calling `getvalue()`.

Comment: `BytesIO(download).getvalue()` is pointless, it converts to a `bytes` object into a `BytesIO` object, then gives you back a `bytes` object...

Comment: I can't find any documentation for `Doc2Vec.load`, but just examples that come up when I google seems to require a *file path as a `str` object*.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Some answers:
-- I didn't post the traceback because I assumed I was doing something basic and dumb.  I remain convinced of that, but I've now posted it.

-- I am indeed initializing and then extracting.  My mistake... I was trying to get it to produce bytes type, and that seemed to do it.
-- I agree that the file path needs to be a string, or at least a reference to a string.  So, maybe I'm thinking about this wrong.  I don't have a file, exactly, I have an in-memory file-like object.

Comment: The traceback isn't complaining that the argument you give to `load` is bytes. It's complaining that `some_bytes_obj.endswith('.gz')` is no good, because `endswith` on a bytes object needs bytes as an argument, not `'.gz'` (which is a string).

Comment: This error occurs because a `bytes` is passed to `Doc2Vec.load()` and further down the chain, `endswith('.gz')` is called on that `bytes`. The library code assumes a `str` (filename) is passed to `Doc2Vec.load()`, but both `str.endswith()` and `bytes.endswith()` are defined so there is no `AttributeError`. However, `bytes.endswith()` expects `bytes` as an argument.

Comment: Gensim opens the filename you give it using the `smart_open` package, rather than vanilla Python `open`. So if you're using Azure, one option is to supply a "filename" that points to your blob, and let `smart_open` handle the downloading. For example, `Doc2Vec.load('azure://my_bucket/my_blob')` Documentation: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open#readme and specifically https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open#azure-credentials